# jbpm 5 create Process instance by bpmn file and get the task details

Tags: jbpm

I am getting the below Exception when created a processInstnace through a bpmn file and want to get the task once created. The below is the stack trace.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.drools.marshalling.impl.MarshallingConfigurationImpl.getObjectMarshallingStrategyStore()Lorg/drools/marshalling/ObjectMarshallingStrategyStore;
at org.jbpm.task.utils.ContentMarshallerHelper.marshal(ContentMarshallerHelper.java:54)
at org.jbpm.process.workitem.wsht.AbstractHTWorkItemHandler.createTaskContentBasedOnWorkItemParams(AbstractHTWorkItemHandler.java:164)
at org.jbpm.process.workitem.wsht.GenericHTWorkItemHandler.executeWorkItem(GenericHTWorkItemHandler.java:179)
at org.drools.process.instance.impl.DefaultWorkItemManager.internalExecuteWorkItem(DefaultWorkItemManager.java:73)
at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.internalTrigger(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:101)
at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:122)
at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerConnection(NodeInstanceImpl.java:185)
at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerCompleted(NodeInstanceImpl.java:150)
at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StartNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(StartNodeInstance.java:49)
at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StartNodeInstance.internalTrigger(StartNodeInstance.java:41)
at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:122)
at org.jbpm.ruleflow.instance.RuleFlowProcessInstance.internalStart(RuleFlowProcessInstance.java:35)
at org.jbpm.process.instance.impl.ProcessInstanceImpl.start(ProcessInstanceImpl.java:188)
at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.start(WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.java:302)
at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcess(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:124)
at org.drools.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.startProcess(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:1099)
at org.drools.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.startProcess(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:302)
at com.sample.TaskServiceMinaSyncTest.regularFlowTest(TaskServiceMinaSyncTest.java:108)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sample.BaseTest.tearDown(BaseTest.java:94)
at com.sample.TaskServiceMinaSyncTest.tearDown(TaskServiceMinaSyncTest.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:36)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I am using thee follwoing code snippet:

```
KnowledgeBase kbase = readKnowledgeBase();
    StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
    GenericHTWorkItemHandler htHandler = createTaskHandler(ksession);
    ksession.getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler("Human Task",htHandler);

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("employee", "ABC");
    ksession.startProcess("com.sample.bpmn.hello", params);
    System.out.println("Process started ...");


 //Creates a local task service and attaches it to a human task handler
    public GenericHTWorkItemHandler createTaskHandler(StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession) {
        TaskService ts = new TaskService(Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("org.jbpm.task"),
                SystemEventListenerFactory.getSystemEventListener());
        LocalTaskService taskService = new LocalTaskService(ts);
        LocalHTWorkItemHandler taskHandler = new LocalHTWorkItemHandler(taskService, ksession);
//        taskHandler.connect();
        this.service = taskService;
        return taskHandler;
    }
```

I have used the follwoing jars(attached screenshot):

![enter image description here][1]

Am getting this error on startProcess line. Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using a mismatch of versions of jBPM and Drools.  Which version of jBPM are you using?  Assuming you are using jBPM 5.4, you should be using Drools 5.5 jars.